# Why do I have to set top/bottom and left/right to 0 in order for my body::before to completely cover the page?

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn the basics of front-end web development and I'm struggling to understand why `body::before` behaves the way it does. I have the following CSS code:

```
body::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.45)), url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/03/05/56/avenue-656969_960_720.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This way the background will appear moved to the bottom-left by some pixels ([CodePen screenshot](https://ibb.co/ynvCKtR)), and will only cover the entirety of the screen if top/bottom and left/right are set to 0. Why does the `body::before` position behave that way but normal body's position doesn't? Also, why doesn't the `body::before` even appear if the position is set to relative?

Comment: See `::before` as a child element of body. In order for it to cover the full size of its parent, it needs to be taken out of the document flow: hence `position: relative` will  not work. The top/bottom/left/right are needed to position the edges of the element.

Comment: Your `<body>` still has the default `margin` styling. Remove it with `body {margin: 0;}`.
Thats why you have the white border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body element by default has margin of 8px on all sides which causes it to move slightly to bottom-right, so when you remove the margins of the body `body { margin: 0; }`, it fixes that.

Secondly, when you set `position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%`, the element goes with the normal flow of the document and takes up 100% of width and height but you did not define the width and height of the body element. So the normal flow of `::before` becomes the 100% of the parent which is 0 (i.e. not defined) and hence doesn't show up. Thus in order to use `position: relative;` on a child element, you need to atleast define the width and height of the parent element with [absolute length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#absolute_length_units).

Hence, the following works

```
body{
  background: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;

  /* 100% is a relative unit and requires its
  parent to have dimensions with absolute units */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the **first child of
> the selected element**. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
> element with the content property. It is **inline by default.**

1. Since ::before pseudo element is first child of body. The background appears moved to the bottom-left by some pixels due to default margin of body element. Because that margin is added to offset of `pseudo element` which has `position:fixed;`.

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position
> value is **absolute or fixed**. The top, right, bottom, and left
> properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing
> block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the
> element is positioned.) **If the element has margins, they are added to
> the offset**. The element establishes a new block formatting context
> (BFC) for its contents.

2. Pseudo element does not appear when we use `position: relative;`. Because in position relative element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, also since **::before pseudo element is inline**, it only takes space required by it and setting **height and width don't work**. Since there is no content it does not take any space, background image disappear. If you want it to cover its full height and width, use `display : inline-block/block;` or just remove it from normal flow of document by using `position:fixed;` which actually **changes the display property to block**.